# Websites Aren't Loading

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, web-development, httpd

The power went out at my house last night. I didn't have a surge protector.  My server went down.  I restarted my router and machine.  I can get an internet connection but my websites and crm are not loading. Any ideas?

When I go to a locally hosted website it says "The connection has timed out".

I just signed into my router to see if the port forwarding had been reset.  It looked good to me.  It doesn't look like anything was reset.  I just ran [systemctl status httpd] and httpd is active.

This is the end of my skill set hahah

httpd is running

Comment: To rule out port forwarding / router / internet issues, did you check if it is accessible from inside of your home network?

Comment: No I did not, how do I do that? I'm still a novice linux user (centos).  I restarted httpd though, didn't work.

Comment: What if you try to open your website from the server where httpd is installed? Using the loopback address? eg. http://localhost:your-port/your-website-address

Answer (score 2):

Check `/etc/resolv.conf` and verify proper DNS server entries; typically your router IP address if using DHCP or ISP DNS servers.  You could test with `1.1.1.1` or `8.8.8.8`.

Run `dig <server>.<domain>` should resolve with IP address of the server you are trying to contact.  Use that IP address in your web browser to see if it will display.

Check firewall rules on local server if that is where you are running Apache on, should have ports 80 (http) and 443 (https) open.

Answer (score 1):

turns out ifconfig says my ip's changed.  I believe this is dynamic dns.